# What's required in order to get OAuth2 credentials for my marketplace app?

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I've created a small application that utilizes the [recently announced Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/) to search received e-mails for a specific string.  My new is app published as hidden in the Chrome / Google Apps store, and I've read that I should be given OAuth2 credentials to use with my application.

For example, [this guide (for the old apps marketplace, which is no longer usable)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-marketplace) shows where a developer can go to grab credentials for their marketplace app:

[image]

However in the new store, I cannot find anywhere that makes these credentials available to me.

Have I missed a step?  Do I need to complete a [Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request](https://docs.google.com/a/consuslabs.com/forms/d/14QOb8PbSLKDgwIp8Zv-luoAAVurPXUqtzL0Hgikp3rk/viewform) in order to be provided credentials?

Thanks!

## Updated with solution

The user MeLight has the answer below - generate service account credentials, then use them after making sure that the project has been linked to the marketplace app in the Chrome Web Store.  For any future Googlers, here's the code used to connect to the API and create a `service` object, which can be used for getting messages, etc.

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.tools import run
import os
import httplib2


BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PRIVATE_KEY = BASEDIR + "XXXX-privatekey.p12"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
SCOPES = ["https://mail.google.com/"]
USERNAME="someone@targetuser.com"

def main(argv):
        f = file(PRIVATE_KEY, 'rb')
        key = f.read()
        f.close()

        credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(service_account_name=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
                                                    private_key=key,
                                                    scope=" ".join(SCOPES),
                                                    prn=USERNAME)

        http = httplib2.Http()

        # Authorize the httplib2.Http object with our credentials
        http = credentials.authorize(http)

        # Build the Gmail service from discovery
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the Cloud Console, you can find it here: https://console.developers.google.com/

Find your project in the list and click it. From there `APIs & AUTH` -> `Credentials`.

You should see a list of clients and their credentials. You'll need a `Service Account` - you can create one if it's not already there.

Comment: I had given that a try, but when I created a service account and attempted to authenticate with it against the Gmail API, the endpoint returned an HTTP status 500 with the message "Backend Error".  My understanding is that not all APIs allow service accounts, especially if they expose user data.  I have no idea if that is the reason for the backend error or not, though.

Comment: I reverted the code to what I had previously tried and it worked immediately.  I'm wondering if the API was stuttering under the load of everyone checking it out last night.  The code, for any future visitors from Google, has been posted in my question. Thanks for your assistance MeLight!

Comment: I totally hear you man - had some troubles finding answers to marketplace questions myself. Glad to hear I could assist :)